# Presto SQL want to use a function on each of all columns, how not to list them one by one?

Tags: sql, presto

Let's say I want an output of something like:
Is it possible to replicate this without explicitly writing out all 100 column names?

```
select main,
count(distinct col1),
count(distinct col2),
...
count(distinct col100),
from table
group by main
```

Comment: No, it is not possible unless you use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Unrelated, you probably do not want to run `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)` over 100 columns. It's not going to perform very well. If you do not need exact answer, I suggest you use [`approx_distinct()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#approx_distinct) instead.